# Union of open sets by a function

Tags: general-topology, functions

Let $E$, $F$ be two topological spaces and $f:E\to F$. Let $(\omega_i)_{i\in I}$ be some open sets of $E$. Under what condition (on the function $f$ or the topological spaces $E,F$) does

$$f\big(\bigcup_{i\in I} \omega_i\big)=\bigcup_{i\in I} f(\omega_i)$$

hold?

Comment: Always true. Any function and any sets will do. You don't need open sets for this.

Comment: This question has been asked here before, please search for it via approach0.xyz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always. Unions of sets commute with images (no topology needed).

Proof: $y \in f[\bigcup_i \omega_i]$ iff

$\exists x \in \bigcup_i \omega_i: f(x)=y$ iff

$\exists j \in I: x \in \omega_j \land f(x)=y$ iff

$\exists j \in I: y \in f[\omega_j]$ iff

$y \in \bigcup_i f[\omega_i]$.

Useful topological applications include: a function is open iff it sends members of some fixed base on the domain to open sets. The continuous image of a $\sigma$-compact space has the same property. So it's nice to know.

Comment: Is there a demonstration ?

Comment: @Hamdiken I added it.

Answer (score 0):

$f(\cup_i A_i)= \cup_i f(A_i)$, where $i \in I$.

1) $f(\cup_i A_i) \subset  \cup_i f(A_i)$.

Let $y \in f(\cup_i A_i)$.

There is an $x \in \cup_i A_i$, and a $k \in I$

with $x \in A_k$  s.t.

$y=f(x) \in f(A_k)  \subset \cup_i f(A_i)$.

2)$\cup_i f(A_i) \subset f(\cup_i A_i)$

Let $y \in \cup_i f(A_i).$

There is a $k \in I$ with $y \in f(A_k)$, and

an $x \in A_k$ with  $y=f(x) \in f(A_k)$.

Since $x \in A_k \subset \cup_i A_i:$

$y=f(x) \in f(\cup_i A_i)$.